# Assets not being see in laravel 5.1 app

Tags: php, css, .htaccess, laravel, laravel-5.1

I use scotchbox and have my app set up as such:

```
app-response-tracker/
  AppResponseTracker/
    app/
    ...
    public/
      css/
        app.css
      js/
        all.js
    resources/
      assets/
      views/
    ...
  public/
    .htaccess/
    favicon.ico
    index.php
    robots.txt
```

In my layouts.main I have the the following html:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <meta name="description" content="App Response Tracker allows you to track the response of applications
    and monitor error output by connecting to a secure end point.">
    <meta name="author" content="Adam Balan">

    <link rel="icon" href="../../favicon.ico">

    <title>App Response Tracker</title>

    <link href="{{asset('css/app.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
```

The line you care about is: `<link href="{{asset('css/app.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">`

In chrome this resolves too: `http://app-response-tracker.com/css/app.css`

According to the [docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/helpers#urls):

> asset
>
> Generate a URL for an asset.
>
> $url = asset('img/photo.jpg');

My htaccess file looks like:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

The site loads fine, the styles don't load at all. How can I fix this?

Comment: Looks like by default the `asset()` helper function points to the public folder.
Since you have added your assets to a public folder inside the app folder you would have to use the `app_path()` helper function, but this does not seems to be a good idea. This would reflect the whole path to your app folder inside your html source code. Just move your assets to the public folder and your good to go.